# Getting Error Message While Connecting Retool with a Bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery, retool

I have been able to successfully integrate Bigquery with Retool on a project. However, right now, I am suddenly seeing the following error message when I try to query my bigquery table from my Retool app:

```
Error: Sorry, we cannot connect to Cloud Services without a project ID. You may specify one with an environment variable named "GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT".
```

I have also tried to create another connection with my bigquery table while following the guidelines in the official Retool documentation here https://docs.retool.com/docs/bigquery but am getting the same error message.

Any pointers on how to resolve this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was fixed by the Retool team.